# Is there a general form for the determinant of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

This came up in trying to deal with small oscillations of an $N$-pendulum. I obviously want to calculate the characteristic polynomial in $\omega^2$ to see if I can deal with the equation even in special cases. Is it the first time you see this kind of matrix? Does the characteristic polynomial have a reasonably nice form? Oh, $N$ is the dimension of the matrix.
You can suppose $m,g,l>0.$

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
 N(mgl-\omega^2ml^2) & -\omega^2ml^2(N-1)&  -\omega^2ml^2(N-2)&...&   -\omega^2ml^2 \\ 
 -\omega^2ml^2(N-1)& (N-1)(mgl-\omega^2ml^2)  &-\omega^2ml^2(N-2)  &...  &-\omega^2ml^2 \\ 
 -\omega^2ml^2(N-2)   &-\omega^2ml^2(N-2)  &(N-2)(mgl-\omega^2ml^2)  & ...& -\omega^2ml^2 \\ 
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots
\end{pmatrix}$$

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: As pointed out by Omnomnomnom (I had to copy paste that name) the problem reduces to finding the determinant of:

$$A = -\omega^2ml^2 
\pmatrix{
N&N-1&N-2&\cdots&1\\
N-1&N-1&N-2&\cdots&1\\
N-2&N-2&N-2&\cdots&1\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
}
+ mgl
\pmatrix{
N\\&N-1\\&&N-2\\&&&\ddots
}=-\omega^2ml^2T+mglV$$
Dividing by $mgl$ and calling $$\tilde\omega=\frac{\omega^2l}{g}$$
We have
$$\operatorname{Det}\bigg(\frac{A}{mgl}\bigg)=\operatorname{Det}B=\operatorname{Det}(V-\tilde\omega T)$$

I computed the first few polynomials in $\tilde \omega$.

For $N=2$
$$P_2(\tilde\omega)= \tilde\omega^2-4\tilde\omega+2$$

For $N=3$:

$$P_3(\tilde\omega)=-\tilde\omega^3+9\tilde\omega^2-18\tilde\omega+6$$

For $N=4$

$$P_4(\tilde\omega)=\tilde\omega^4-16\tilde\omega^3+72\tilde\omega^2-96\tilde\omega+24$$

For $N=5$

$$P_5(\tilde\omega)= -\tilde\omega^5+25\tilde\omega^4-200\tilde\omega^3+600\tilde\omega^2-600\tilde\omega+120$$
Do you see a pattern? The first coefficient might be $(-1)^N$, the second $N^2(-1)^{N+1}$, the last one is probably $N!$, the second to last one might be $-N!N$.

Comment: It might help to factor out the $\omega^2ml^2$

Comment: Don't know how much it helps, but it seems related http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternant_matrix

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but a helpful note: we can write this matrix as
$$
A = -\omega^2m\ell^2 
\pmatrix{
N&N-1&N-2&\cdots&1\\
N-1&N-1&N-2&\cdots&1\\
N-2&N-2&N-2&\cdots&1\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
}
+ mg\ell
\pmatrix{
N\\&N-1\\&&N-2\\&&&\ddots
}
$$
After we factor out the second matrix, I'd imagine we could say something nice about the eigenvalues of the first.

Comment: Yeah, that's the form I started with (namely, the first one is the kinetic energy matrix, the second one the potential energy matrix), but I honestly didn't know what to do with those matrices.

Comment: First of all, this form is **a lot** easier to look at.  The idea I have is as follows: we now have something of the form 
$$aP + bQ$$
for numbers $a,b$ and matrices $P,Q$.  We can rewrite this as
$$
P(aP^{-1}Q + bI)
$$
If we could find the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_N$ of the matrix $P^{-1}Q$, then our determinant could be written as
$$
\det(P)\cdot \prod_{i=1}^N (a\lambda_i + b) =
N!\cdot \prod_{i=1}^N (a\lambda_i + b)
$$
So, if we can find those eigenvalues, then we're done.

Comment: I don't think there's a nice general expression for the eigenvalues of $P^{-1}Q$, so that doesn't look like a great way to approach this after all.

Comment: Perhaps we can do something nice with the characteristic polynomial of the matrix, though... (without having to factor it)

Comment: Yeah, I honestly thought so. Your approach would basically mean finding the roots of the polynomial in the general case, and it is well known that algebraic equations of high order are difficult to solve analytically (and if it were possible it would probably be done as an exercise in analytical mechanics courses). Nice try though, I learnt from it. It seems that finding a general expression for the characteristical polynomial is not as daunting a task: the polynomials I wrote don't seem excessively bad.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the matrix
$$
P^{-1}Q = 
\pmatrix{
N\\&N-1\\&&N-2\\&&&\ddots
}^{-1}
\pmatrix{
N&N-1&N-2&\cdots&1\\
N-1&N-1&N-2&\cdots&1\\
N-2&N-2&N-2&\cdots&1\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
} = \\
\pmatrix{
1&1-1/N&1-2/N&\cdots&1/N\\
1&1&1 - 1/(N-1)&\cdots&1/(N-1)\\
1&1&1&\cdots&1/(N-2)\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
}
$$
Let $q_N(x)$ denote the characteristic polynomial $\det(P^{-1}Q - xI)$.
The answer to the determinant we seek will be
$$
\det(A) = N! \cdot a^N q_N(-b) = 
N! (-\omega^2 m \ell^2)^N q_N(- mg \ell)
$$
Hopefully you find this expression useful.